# Accord de l'adjectif dans la formule « avoir l'air »

Tags: expressions, adjectifs, genre, accord

Si ma sœur semble fatiguée, je pourrais écrire :

1. Ma sœur a l'air **fatigué**.
2. Ma sœur a l'air **fatiguée**.

L'une ou l'autre forme peut être justifiée :

1. L'adjectif *fatigué* qualifie l'air, et *air* est masculin.
2. La formule se rapporte à ma sœur, et *sœur* est féminin.

La première forme me semble la plus correcte, mais la seconde est largement plus utilisée — oralement du moins.

Quelle forme est correcte ? Les deux ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

L'accord se fait avec le ***sujet*** :

- quand il s'agit de **choses**:

  - ces blés ont l'air *mûrs*... (ils ont l'air d'être mûrs)
- quand il s'agit de **personnes**, si l'on peut dire *sembler, paraître*:

  - cette fillette a l'air *douce*... (elle semble douce)
- si le **sens interdit** l'accord avec air:

  - elle a l'air *bavarde*... (on ne peut pas avoir une mine bavarde !).

L'accord se fait avec ***air*** :

- dans le sens de **mine, physionomie**:

  - cette personne a l'air *sérieux*... (c'est son air qui est sérieux)
- quand ce nom a un **complément**:

  - elle a l'air *sérieux* d'une grande personne...

[source](http://mapage.noos.fr/marcpage/bof.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Les deux tournures sont grammaticalement correctes et sont idiomatiques. C'est le sens qui départage. Ici, les deux sont possibles. En général, tout de même, c'est plutôt au sujet que l'adjectif se rapporte ; « un air [adjectif] » n'est pas une tournure aussi courante qu'« avoir l'air ».

On peut faire quelques tests pour comparer le ressenti du rattachement de l'adjectif à l'air ou au sujet :

- choisir un sujet féminin et un adjectif qui varie en sonorité : « elle a l'air peu vivant(e) » ;
- utiliser *un air* à la place de *l'air*, ce qui n'est possible que si l'adjectif se rattache à l'air : « elle a un air fatigué », « elle a un air distingué », « <strike>elle a un air prêt</strike> » ;
- ajouter un qualificatif qui différencie l'air du sujet : « elle a l'air le plus fatigué (que je lui aie jamais vu) », « elle a l'air la plus fatiguée (du groupe) ».

Answer (score 0):

Selon mes souvenirs lointains …
Quand on peut remplacer avoir l'air par "semble être", forcément c'est avec le sujet qu'on fait l'accord.

Comment: Il faudrait améliorer la réponse en cherchant des sources sur internet. Parce que les souvenirs lointains, c'est trompeur.