# Est-ce qu'il est correct de dire "elle a l’air comme neuve" plutôt que "comme neuf"

Tags: adjectifs

De "L'Embrasement" par Suzanne Collins

> Ma ceinture-bouée doit être résistante à l’acide, car elle a l’air
>   comme neuve.

Il me semble que "neuve" décrit l'apparence (m. air) et pas l'objet lui-même, donc est-ce une erreur ?

Comment: Dans cette formulation, neuve se rapportant à ceinture, c'est comme si on écrivait: "car elle a l'air comme (si elle était) neuve"

Comment: It's the same as in https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1606. But notice that *comme* can only be inserted in the *avoir l'air* construction.

Answer (score -1):

Dans ce contexte, « elle a l'air comme » peut se traduire par « seems », « neuve » est accordé à « elle », pas à « air. »

Comment: @Toto: Sorry I don't use the " and ' properly in english it seems. Leur usage est il différent dans les deux langues?