# Accord avec « avoir l'air »

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Je modifie légèrement la question pour qu'elle ne soit pas duplicata de la question ici :

[Accord de l'adjectif dans la formule « avoir l'air »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/accord-de-ladjectif-dans-la-formule-avoir-lair)

---

**EDIT**

Avec la locution **avoir l'air** l'accord se fait généralement avec le sujet.

> Cette fillette a l'air fatiguée. Cette pomme a l'air appétissante.

Selon la grammaire du français, l'accord avec **air** est possible, si le sujet est un **nom animé**.

> Cette fillette a l'air fatigué.  Cette pomme a l'air bonne (et pas
>   bon).

Par ailleurs, la réponse

[Accord de l'adjectif dans la formule « avoir l'air »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/accord-de-ladjectif-dans-la-formule-avoir-lair/1607#1607)

donne la façon d'accord. Cependant, j'ai quelques questions à poser :

1) Pourquoi cette différence entre noms animé et inanimé ?

2) Pourquoi n'existe-t-il une règle uniforme d'accord dans la grammaire du français ? Soit avec **air**, soit avec le **sujet** ?

Plus généralement, je trouve que l'existence de telles exceptions et contre-exemples d'accord dans la grammaire fait l'apprentissage difficile pour les écoliers et les adultes.

Comment: "This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question" Je ne vois pas en quoi c'est un duplicata. Dans un cas il est demandé "Quelle forme est correcte ?", dans l'autre "Pourquoi ?". Il me semble que la question de dimitris reprend la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1607/9543) de l'autre question et renchérit.

Comment: [Ma réponse](https://pastebin.com/VV5WPiCt), au cas où cela intéresserait quelqu'un ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je donne ci-dessous la [réponse exhaustive](https://pastebin.com/VV5WPiCt) de @Georg (merci !) pour qu'elle soit aussi disponible dans FSE.

1) Différence entre animés et inanimés

- Accord avec le sujet.

Ici, "avoir l'air" est à prendre comme une expression d'un bloc, qui signifie "paraître". On peut écrire "cette fillette paraît fatiguée, cette pomme paraît appétissante", et remplacer "paraît" par "avoir l'air" sans se poser de question. Comme il s'agit d'une expression, l'article défini (l'air) ne peut pas être remplacé par l'article indéfini (un air).

La phrase est à voir comme ceci : sujet (fillette), verbe (paraître, ou son synonyme "avoir l'air"), adjectif se rapportant au sujet (fatiguée).

- Accord avec "air".

Le point de vue n'est plus le même. La phrase est à voir comme ceci : sujet (fillette), verbe (avoir), complément (air), adjectif se rapportant au complément (fatigué).

On considère ici que le sujet a un air (au sens de : une mine, une expression), ce qui n'est envisagé que dans le cas d'un être animé, et on caractérise ensuite cet air (cette mine) : fatigué, triste, joyeux...

On ne peut pas dire qu'une pomme est joyeuse - sauf si on l'humanise, et pourquoi pas après tout... Il n'est donc pas impossible de dire qu'une pomme a un air joyeux, mais c'est une figure de style, une fantaisie. Votre manuel de grammaire, qui reste sérieux, ne l'envisage pas.

2) Difficulté de la grammaire.

Je ne nie pas l'existence d'exceptions et des règles réellement arbitraires. J'espère avoir montré ci-dessus qu'une règle qui semble arbitraire peut parfois s'éclairer quand on en comprend la logique.

Mais je voudrais faire passer un autre message : si vous avez des examens à passer ou si vous vous destinez à une carrière de linguiste, apprenez, travaillez et souffrez. En revanche, si vous voulez juste parler français (cas de la grande majorité des gens qui apprennent le français), détendez-vous car il n'est pas nécessaire de connaître parfaitement toutes ces règles pour bien parler ni même pour écrire. Beaucoup de Français ne les connaissent d'ailleurs pas.

Dans le cas présent, oubliez simplement l'accord avec "air" et les questions d'animés/inanimés, accordez toujours avec le sujet et vous écrirez sans faute. C'est ce que la plupart des gens font.

Comment: Il faudrait marquer cette réponse comme acceptée, alors.