# Quand est-ce que le 'h' n'est pas muet ?

Tags: prononciation, h-aspiré

J'entends souvent dire: "devant voyelle ou 'h' muet".

Mais, quand est-ce que le 'h' n'est pas muet ? Seulement après un 'c', n'est-ce pas ? Comme dans la phrase suivante: "Il faut que tu sa**ch**es ..."

Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres possibilités ?

Comment: [How can we distinguish “H-muet” or “H-aspiré”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1833)

Comment: Imo, you (& @dimitris with [this recent question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30089)) too quickly “approved [the] pending duplicate vote” on your question, which approval caused the immediate marking as duplicate by “Community” of your question, prior to the issue getting a full vote & in spite of there being arguable distinctions between the questions: eg Although the earlier “question” certainly reads like a duplicate in its “Title Header,” its body doesn’t read like a question at all, but rather, to me, more like a “fill-in-the-blank” exercise from a person’s French homework.

Comment: @PapaPoule: Thanks for mentioning my question. It rests one single vote to be reopened. In this way I can add the response of Georg which gave an exhaustive answer. His response is available in a link mentioned in a comment but it deserves to be available in french exchange.

Comment: @dimitris Your good question already has my vote to be reopened (as does this one) and I wish them both success.  Not to try to tell you or anyone else how to handle the relatively new [user interface window that appears, only to its author, when a question receives a "duplicate" vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930), but no one should ever feel at all obliged to hit the "That solved my problem" button, especially when the question's author has a possibly clarifying edit in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La Lettre H ne correspond à aucun son. Selon l'origine du mot (latine, germanique ou anglaise) elle est considérée comme une voyelle ou comme une consonne.

H vocalique:

> l'homme, l'humanité, hésiter (j'hésite), des honneurs (liaison i.e. z son), etc.

H consonantique :

> haïr->Je hais (et pas j'hais), le hamburger, le homard, les hors-d'oeuvre, etc.

En général il n'y a pas de règle pour distinguer les deux cas. Il faut apprendre par coeur les différents mots.

Cependant il y a certains cas qui pourraient s'expliquer avec la logique.

P. ex. les héros (pas liaison) sinon la prononciation serait identique à les zéros :-)!

Vous pouvez apprendre les plus fréquents mots qui commencent avec h aspiré progressivement. Voir

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-61194.php

Évidement la liste est loin d'être complète :

http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire01ac.htm

La discussion suite de la question indiquée dans les commentaires comporte plus de détails.

Answer (score 4):

Il y a quatre cas pour la prononciation de la lettre `h` en français.

- Le `h` se prononce en soufflant : [h]. Ceci n'existe que dans quelques onomatopées : *ha* [ha], *hi* [hi], ...
- Le `h` ne se prononce pas tout seul, mais modifie la prononciation de la consonne précédente. Le digramme `ch` se prononce en général [[ʃ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_fricative_palato-alv%C3%A9olaire_sourde)] (*chat* [ʃ], *chose* [ʃoz]), mais il se prononce [k] dans des mots d'origine grecque (*orchestre* [ɔʁ.kɛstʁ], *chœur* [kœʁ]). Le digramme `ph` se prononce [f] (*photographie* [fo.to.gʁa.fi]).
- Le `h` ne se prononce pas du tout. On prononce exactement comme s'il n'était pas là. Si le `h` est en début de mot et que le mot précédent eut s'élider s'élide, on l'élide (*le* → *l'*, *me* → *m'*, *ne* → *n'*, *se* → *s'*, …). On peut faire une liaison « par-dessus » le `h`. C'est un **h muet**. Exemples : *habit* [a.bi] (*l'habit* [la.bi], *un bel habit* [œ̃.bɛl.a.bi], *un gros habit* [œ̃.gʁo‿za.bi]), *héroïne* [e.ʁo.in] (*l'héroïne* [le.ʁo.in]*), *trahir* [tʁa.iʁ], *rhume* [ʁym], *thèse* [tɛz], ...
- Le `h` ne se prononce pas, mais on fait semblant. Il est en début de mot, et on ne prononce pas le `h` lui-même, mais on considère que le mot commence par une consonne pour prononcer le mot précédent. Le mot précédent ne s'élide pas et on ne fait jamais de liaison. On appelle ce cas un **[H aspiré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_aspir%C3%A9)**, mais malgré le nom il n'y a pas d'aspiration dans la prononciation. Exemples : *hameau* ['a.mo] (*le hameau* [lə.'a.mo], *un beau hameau* [œ̃.bo.a.mo], *un gros hameau* [œ̃.gʁo.a.mo]), *héros* [e.ʁo] (*le héros* [lə.'eʁo]*), ...

Quand un `h` est en début de mot, il n'y a pas de règle pour savoir s'il est muet ou aspiré. Ce sont en général les mots d'origine latine ou grecque qui ont un `h` muet, mais il y a des exceptions dans les deux sens.

Comment: Une réponse parfaite et complète. Bravo !